# HashSet of objects whose properties need to be the keys

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, data-structures

I have a Unity project in which various *Cords* are stretched between various *Hooks*. The player can grab one end of a cord from its hook, carry it, and attach it to another. As part of this functionality, the hook needs to keep track of which cords are attached to it, and when the player tries to attach a new one, check that doing so won't 'disappear' the cord (ie. they're not hooking both ends to the same place, and the cord won't merge with another by being attached to the same hooks at both ends).

Each `Cord` object has `start` and `end` properties that refer to the `Hook`s to which it's attached. Currently, I've been keeping track with a `List`:

```
public class Hook : MonoBehaviour {

    List<Cord> attached = new List<Cord>();

    public void Attach(Cord c) {
        if (!ConflictTest(c))
            attached.Add(c);
    }

    public void Detach(Cord c) {
        attached.Remove(c);
    }

    bool ConflictTest(Cord toAttach) {
        foreach (Cord c in attached) {
            // canonically, a cord is grabbed by its 'end', so we only check its 'start'
            if (c.start == toAttach.start || c.end == toAttach.start)
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

I realised that this linear search in `ConflictTest()`, which is actually executed at every `OnMouseEnter()` and `OnMouseDown()` isn't ideal. I would like to change the data structure of `attached` to a `HashSet`, but is there a way I can set things up so I can do the test in terms of the HashSet's `Contains()` method (ie. `attached.Contains(toAttach.start)`)? Since I need to refer to the `start` and `end` properties of each member of the set, it seems I either need to a separate set for each property (but then how do I coordinate additions and removals?) or to somehow allow the properties to be keys. Any ideas?

Comment: How about using a HashMap<Cord, boolean> or HashMap<Id, Cord> and use containsKey?

Comment: @Adder Not sure how those help. Explain?

Comment: Different Collection Type Classes have different contracts regarding the time and memory complexity of the class. I.e. A list as you noticed has O(n) i.e. linear complexity for finding a match in the list. A HashMap uses a Hash table and has a bit more than O(1) i.e. constant complexity for looking up an object using the Hash. I'm not really sure about the HashSet and how it works, maybe it is also a good choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this is to expand your `List<Cord>` into a `Dictionary<Hook, Cord>`, where the key represents the `Hook` end point of the value `Cord` that is not the current one. This `Hook` recorded is guaranteed to be unique since a `Hook` will only ever have at most one `Cord` validly connecting it to another `Hook`. Here's how this might look (extra commenting for clarity):

```
public class Hook : MonoBehaviour {

    // Stores a Cord and its "other" Hook
    Dictionary<Hook, Cord> attached = new Dictionary<Hook, Cord>();

    // Add a Cord by retrieving its "other" Hook and using it as a key
    public void Attach(Cord c) {
        if (!ConflictTest(c)){
            attached.Add(GetOtherHook(c), c);
        }
    }

    // Remove a cord based on its "other" Hook
    public void Detach(Cord c) {
        attached.Remove(GetOtherHook(c));
    }

    // Determine whether current connections contain this Cord's "other" Hook
    bool ConflictTest(Cord toAttach) {
        return attached.ContainsKey(GetOtherHook(toAttach));
    }

    // Retrieves the "other" (non-current Hook) a cord is attached to
    private Hook GetOtherHook(Cord c) {
        return c.end != this ? c.end : c.start;
    }
}
```

Hope this helps! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Ah you're quite right! Somehow I hadn't considered that I'm only actually interested in one end of each cord. I was also worried that I would be removing by value, but with your `GetOtherHook` function that need not be the case. In fact I could probably reduce it to a HashSet after all.

Comment: I'm still curious about the abstract problem though... If there were a situation where multiple properties needed to be checked, what would you propose?

Comment: @Igid If each combination of properties has to be unique, then you could consider joining them together into a single value (either by hashing or just concatenating them into a string), then using that as the key for the `HashSet`. On the other hand, if property had to be unique (and not just a given combination of them), then you could have multiple `HashSet` collections.